# Can't get UpdatePanel to work as intended?

Tags: c#, .net

I have three dropdowns on a page.

(1) Holds Parking Structures - parkingArea
(2) Holds the levels for the selected (1) - ddParkingAreaLevel
(3) The slots available for (2) - ddAvailableParkingSlots

When someone changes (1), (2) is uploaded with the levels for (1) and then (3) is updated with the slots available for the level selected (2).

However, this just does not work. I am not very familiar with UpdatePanel and simply cant get it to work as intended.

They way it works now:

When I change (1), (2) is updated correctly and (3) loads the slots for (2). But, if I change (2), the UpdatePanel is triggered but slots are NOT loaded into (3) and (2) "jumps back" to SelectedIndex at value 0, and does not stay at the newly selected level.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="parkingArea" runat="server">
  <label>Parking Area:</label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddParkingAreas" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"
style="width:240px;" onselectedindexchanged="ddParkingAreas_SelectedIndexChanged"
AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Level:</label>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddParkingAreaLevel" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"
style="width:240px;" onselectedindexchanged="ddParkingAreaLevel_SelectedIndexChanged"
AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddParkingAreas"
EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /></Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>     


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Available Parking Slots:</label>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAvailableParkingSlots" CssClass="form-control" 
runat="server" style="width:240px;"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddParkingAreaLevel"
EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /></Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope any of you guys can help!

Regards,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one update panel for all cascading dropdowns?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpMain" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>

    <div class="form-group" id="parkingArea" runat="server">
      <label>Parking Area:</label>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddParkingAreas" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" style="width:240px;" onselectedindexchanged="ddParkingAreas_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Level:</label>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddParkingAreaLevel" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" style="width:240px;" onselectedindexchanged="ddParkingAreaLevel_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Available Parking Slots:</label>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAvailableParkingSlots" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" style="width:240px;"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>

</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="ddParkingAreas"  EventName="ddParkingAreas_SelectedIndexChanged" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="ddAvailableParkingSlots"  EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>    
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```